# Failed to compile. ./src/app/menu/menu.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../shared/dishes'

Tags: angular

Im getting the following error:
Failed to compile.

./src/app/menu/menu.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../shared/dishes' in '/Users/parthiljagani/Desktop/git-test2/Angular/conFusion/src/app/menu'

and I have attached my codes below. Please help me find the error.
Thank you.

This is my dishes.ts code:

```
import { Dish } from "./dish";

export const DISHES: Dish[]= [
    {
        id: '0',
        name: 'Uthappizza',
        image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        featured: true,
        label: 'Hot',
        price: '4.99',
        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
        description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
                rating: 5,
                comment: 'Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!',
                author: 'John Lemon',
                date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: 'Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!',
                author: 'Paul McVites',
                date: '2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 3,
                comment: 'Eat it, just eat it!',
                author: 'Michael Jaikishan',
                date: '2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: 'Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!',
                author: 'Ringo Starry',
                date: '2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 2,
                comment: 'It\'s your birthday, we\'re gonna party!',
                author: '25 Cent',
                date: '2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Zucchipakoda',
        image: '/assets/images/zucchipakoda.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        featured: false,
        label: '',
        price: '1.99',
        description: 'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
        comments: [
            {
                rating: 5,
                comment: 'Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!',
                author: 'John Lemon',
                date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: 'Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!',
                author: 'Paul McVites',
                date: '2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 3,
                comment: 'Eat it, just eat it!',
                author: 'Michael Jaikishan',
                date: '2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: 'Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!',
                author: 'Ringo Starry',
                date: '2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 2,
                comment: 'It\'s your birthday, we\'re gonna party!',
                author: '25 Cent',
                date: '2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Vadonut',
        image: '/assets/images/vadonut.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        featured: false,
        label: 'New',
        price: '1.99',
        description: 'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
        comments: [
            {
                rating: 5,
                comment: 'Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!',
                author: 'John Lemon',
                date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: 'Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!',
                author: 'Paul McVites',
                date: '2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 3,
                comment: 'Eat it, just eat it!',
                author: 'Michael Jaikishan',
                date: '2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: 'Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!',
                author: 'Ringo Starry',
                date: '2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 2,
                comment: 'It\'s your birthday, we\'re gonna party!',
                author: '25 Cent',
                date: '2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        name: 'ElaiCheese Cake',
        image: '/assets/images/elaicheesecake.png',
        category: 'dessert',
        featured: false,
        label: '',
        price: '2.99',
        description: 'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
        comments: [
            {
                rating: 5,
                comment: 'Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!',
                author: 'John Lemon',
                date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: 'Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!',
                author: 'Paul McVites',
                date: '2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 3,
                comment: 'Eat it, just eat it!',
                author: 'Michael Jaikishan',
                date: '2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: 'Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!',
                author: 'Ringo Starry',
                date: '2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
            },
            {
                rating: 2,
                comment: 'It\'s your birthday, we\'re gonna party!',
                author: '25 Cent',
                date: '2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
            }
        ]
    }
];

This is my menu.component.ts code:

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
import { DISHES } from "../shared/dishes";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  dishes: Dish[] = DISHES;

  selectedDish: Dish = DISHES[0];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}

This is my dish.ts code: 

import { Comment } from "./comment";
export class Dish{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    image: string;
    category: string;
    featured: boolean;
    label: string;
    price: string;
    description: string;
    comments: Comment[];
}

This is my comment.ts code:

export class Comment {
  rating: number;
  comment: string;
  author: string;
  date: string;
}
```

Comment: did you imported your shared module in your component and export dishes in shared one?

Comment: create  a demo on stackblatz and share link

Comment: We need to see your module where menu component imported